# How can I change styling of portions of an input as the user types, using React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Similar to many markdown editors, I would like to be able to modify portions of an input field as the user types. For example:

[image]

If the user types the above, immediately as the closing underscore is typed, the text should be styled as below.

[image]

And then if either (now faded and grey) underscore is removed, it reverts back to plain text and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can add styled-components to be able to change dynamically the style of the input. and add event linked to the typing like onKeypress
[you can see more on the documentation](https://styled-components.com/)